# Path error in Django project: Argument of type HttpResponse | None

Tags: python, django

**Error Description**

```
(function) signupuser(request: Unknown) -> (HttpResponse | None)
Argument of type "(request: Unknown) -> (HttpResponse | None)" cannot be assigned to parameter "view" of type "List[URLResolver | str]" in function "path"
  "object" is incompatible with "List[URLResolver | str]"
```

## Clean version of the code without changes

**urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
```

### Code version after my changes

**urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #Auth
    path('signup/', views.signupuser, name='signupuser')
    #Todos
```

The error appeared when adding `if` to the `def signupuser` function to the file:

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        if request.POST.get['password1'] == request.POST.get['password2']:
            try:
                user= User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Password did not match'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Password did not match'})
```

**settings.py**

There are only changes in this file: `todo` added to `INSTALLED_APPS`

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-fjaa8d=4^4fn^=&ed(=3+l1_*)vzmu&(a+)omp9o6u)1(+)dff'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'todo',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'todowo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'todowo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

When the file **views.py** it looks like this, there is no error

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login

def signupuser(request):
    return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html')
```

Why vs code sees an error, how to fix it?
Please help, thank you in advance

I thought maybe the interpreter was chosen the wrong one, maybe something is conflicting

Comment: I can try to solve this ping me on hemant.yadav1059@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the reason that it is seeing this as an error is python can't determine if you are returning a rendered request.

```
def review(request):
    return render(request, 'reviews/index.html')

vs.

def user(request):
    if true:
       return render(request, 'reviews/user.html')
    else:
       return render(request, 'reviews/signup.html')
```

in the first example Django knows what is going to be returned, where in the second there are multiple return statements. I might be wrong but I think if you refactor the function with out if statements your error will go away.